# Is there a default interface for the simplest callback in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, callback

I need a simple interface for using it as lambda function parameter. Something like:

```java
    interface Callback<T> {
        void handle(T result);
    }
```

Is there anything similar in java core?

Comment: java.util.function.Consumer. Check out the rest of [the package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). There's pretty much every combination of methods with 0, 1 or 2 arguments, with and without a return value, for both objects and primitives.

Comment: @Michael, Yes, Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, even if your interface is covered by one of these types, it is still nice to define your own, so that you have the opportunity to give it a more meaningful name (and add JavaDocs, annotations etc.)